# Need proper driver for IBM x206m xserver graphics chip

Tags: drivers, 13.10, ati

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on an IBM x206m server but the graphics is sluggish/lagging when opening/moving the windows. The "about your system" window indicate that a default driver from Gallium LLVMPIPE file is being used. A search on the IBM site indicate that the x206m server is using an ATI (ES1000) on-board graphics chip. Which driver(and how) do i install the proper driver to correct this sluggish/lagging display symptom.

I am a newbie; I will need step-by-step instructions

Answer (score 0):

Some searching revealed that ES1000 = RV100 = Radeon 7000.

So use the AMD Catalyst driver and you can find it here with installation instructions: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86

Then again ... when talking ATI the only choice is the Catalyst driver ;)